# MySQL - storing numbers with decimal point

Tags: mysql, numbers, decimal, points

exist any way to store in database a numbers with or without decimal point? The user can store to database numbers like **10** and **10.1** - for storing numbers in MySQL I use data type column **decimal**, so for this example, in the database will be stored **10.00** and **10.10**.

But I will need to store the exact form of number by user - so in this case 0 **10** and **10.1**.

Is possible to solve it on database level or I have to edit on application level?

Comment: This is not a storage problem, but a display problem. As such it has nothing to do with the database. And what would you want to do if the user actually entered **10.0**?

Comment: Show the code you use to display the stored value, that's where your problem is.

Comment: I am able to solve it in code, but I interested if is possible to do it some more clear way - eg. direct in database. It looks probably not, so I have to write an own function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use on `case`

```
case format(@number,0)=@number 
  when 1 then format(@number,0) 
  else 
  case format(@number,1)=@number 
    when 1 then format(@number,1) 
    else @number
  end 
end
```

or `if`

```
if (format(@number,0)=@number, format(@number,0),
  if (format(@number,1)=@number, format(@number,1), @number))
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is when you make the select query to omit this leading zero

http://www.foscode.com/remove-trailing-zeros-mysql-decimal-fields/

Answer (score -2):

You could just save whatever the user entered as a VARCHAR, so you'll store exactly what they entered.  Then when you need it, you can load it from the DB, and parse it to the corresponding float value as needed.

Comment: In my country we call this the "arm hurts? cut head!" treatment.